# 2.1.4-java - How to use @options helper with Map<String, String> as parameter

Tags: java, playframework

I am creating a custom HTML to get input for the phone number. This is supposed to be a controls group with select box for phone type and a text box for the phone number. The layout needs to be different from what is done with build-in HTML helpers @select and @inputText. So my code looks as follows:

```
@phoneGroup(field: Field, className: String = "phone") = {
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="@field("type").id">@Messages("company.phoneNumbers")</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select id="@field("type").id" name="@field("type").name">
        @options(models.PhoneType.options)
      </select>
      <input type="text" id="@field("number").id" name="@field("number").name" value="@field("number").value">
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

And I call it below in my template as follows:

```
@repeat(companyForm("phones"), min = 2) { phone =>
  @phoneGroup(phone)
}
```

In the resulting HTML everything looks good so far except for the part that is generated by

```
@options(models.PhoneType.options)
```

Here's an HTML that is generated:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="phones_0__type">Phone numbers</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="phones_0__type" name="phones[0].type">
      (MAI,Main)(MOB,Mobile)(FAX,Fax)(CUS,Custom)
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="phones_0__number" name="phones[0].number" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Apparently, @options just output string representation of the Map I am passing to it in models.PhoneType.options. So the question is, how do I use @options helper to generate the following HTML:

```
<option value="MAI">Main</option>
<option value="MOB">Mobile</option>
<option value="FAX">Fax</option>
<option value="CUS">Custom</option>
```

I am a Java programmer and I don't have any experience with Scala. It's probably a trivial thing but I didn't find any examples.

Thank you in advance.
- Dmitri

**UPDATED 2013-11-07 - posted solution in the Answer section below**

Answer (score 0):

@options is just an object and doesn't handle outputting the HTML itself.  That is done in the "select" helper where you pass in the options object.  If you can't use @select, you could copy the relevant bits out of the source, https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/select.scala.html.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the clues, David. The reason I didn't use @select is because it also generates some formatting HTML around select tag and I wanted to have control over laying out components. Since I didn't figure out how to properly customize @select I went this road for now. OK, as you suggested I just copied the options Scala code and it did the trick:

```
<select id="@field("type").id" name="@field("type").name" class="input-small">
    @options(models.PhoneType.options).map { v =>
        <option value="@v._1" 
            @if(Some(v._1) == (field("type").value)) { selected  }>@v._2</option>
    }
</select>
```

The only catch, I had to use Some(v._1) as in inputRadioButtonGroup code ( https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/inputRadioGroup.scala.html ), otherwise the comparison didn't work. I have to learn a little bit of scala to understand why is that :)

Or alternatively, the for loop works too, as follows:

```
<select id="@field("type").id" name="@field("type").name" class="input-small">
    @for((value, text) <- models.PhoneType.options) {
        <option value="@value" 
            @if(Some(value) == (field("type").value)) { selected  }>@text</option>
    }
</select>
```